# C Assign Pointer to NULL

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am misunderstanding something basic about pointers in C, this should be simple but search brings up nothing. I do not understand the behaviour of the following code;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_function(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(10);

    if(ptr != NULL) printf("FIRST TEST: ptr is not null\n");
    else printf("FIRST TEST: ptr is null\n");

    my_function(ptr);

    if(ptr != NULL) printf("SECOND TEST: ptr is not null\n");
    else printf("SECOND TEST: ptr is null\n");
}

void my_function(char *a) {
    a = NULL;
}
```

Which outputs;

```
FIRST TEST: ptr is not null
SECOND TEST: ptr is not null
```

Why does the second test still see the pointer as not NULL? I am trying to use a NULL pointer assignment as a sort of 'return flag' to indicate a certain failure of the function. But upon testing the pointer afterwards, it does not seem to be NULL.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's because the pointer is passed by value and not by reference. If you want to change the pointer inside the function you need to pass the actual pointer as a pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer:

```
void my_function(char **a)
{
    *a = NULL;
}
```

Use the address-of operator `&` when you call the function to get the address of the pointer:

```
my_function(&ptr);
```

Comment: It suddenly struck me how dumb this was just before you answered, I need a pointer to a pointer in order to be able to assign the outer pointer!

Answer (score 7):

Your statement `a=NULL` in `my_function()` indeed sets the value of `a` to `NULL`, but `a` is a local variable of that function.When you passed `ptr` to `my_function()` in `main()`, the value of `ptr` was copied to `a`.I suppose your whole confusion arose from the `*` used before `a` in the definition of `my_function()`.

Pointers are generally passed to functions when we want to manipulate the original values which those pointers point to, from the called function, and this is done by `dereferencing` those pointers from the called  functions.In this case, had you used this:

```
*a= blah blah;
```

it would have reflected in the value at the address pointed to by `ptr` in `main()`.But since you want to change the value of `ptr` itself, you need to be able to have a way to `manipulate` it from `my_function()`.For this you use a `pointer-to-pointer`,ie of type `char**`.You pass such a `char**` as argument to `my_function(()` and use it to alter the value of `ptr`.Here's the variation to your code that would do it for you:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_function(char **); // Change char* to char**

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(10);

    if(ptr != NULL) printf("FIRST TEST: ptr is not null\n");
    else printf("FIRST TEST: ptr is null\n");

    my_function(&ptr); //You pass a char**

    if(ptr != NULL) printf("SECOND TEST: ptr is not null\n");
    else printf("SECOND TEST: ptr is null\n");
}

void my_function(char **a) {  //Change char* to char** here
    *a = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in C, a function call like `foo(a)` will never change the value of a.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should take a `char** a` if you want to modify what it points to.  This is because pointers are **copied** as arguments to a function, meaning that any changes you make to it inside, will not be seen outside the function, as its modifying a copy.

If you want to change it and see it outside the function scope, you need to add another indirection.

Answer (score 0):

when passing the pointer to the function the pointer is copied into functions scope. you need to use a pointer of pointer if you want do such things. A pointer is basicly only an integer/long

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `my_pointer` gets does not write to the pointer `ptr`, but its copy, `*a`.

You need to pass the address of `ptr` do to what you want.